# Restore previous version of a folder when the owner is deleted

Tags: windows-7, permissions, volume-shadow-copy, previous-versions

How to restore a previous folder version in Windows 7 (using the built-in shadow copy functionality) when the user that owned the folder is deleted? I can not change ownership as it denies me permission to do so.
I do have access to an administrator account.

The owner is now `Unknown User-S#X...` where `S#X` is a long string of characters and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know Windows 7 in detail but in former Windows versions you could change the folder owner (right click, properties, security, advanced properties, owner). After changing the folder owner to your admin you could change security settings / permissions.
Before you could do this, you have to copy the files/folder from the backup space to normal space on your hard drive. To learn how you could do this please got to [Recovering A Deleted Windows 7 Offline Files Cache](http://mediarealm.com.au/articles/2013/03/recovering-a-deleted-windows-7-offline-files-cache-with-volume-shadow-services/).

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me, but as I state in my question `I can not change ownership as it denies me permission to do so`.

Comment: An administrator have always the permission to change the ownership, because he is the administrator :).

Comment: Yes, I also thought that. However it didn't work as it should. What did work is starting `cmd` as an admin, then killing the explorer task and restarting it, end then copying the previous version of the desired folder to the Desktop.